# What does "optimal balance of biological control" mean in nematodes?

Tags: entomology, pathology, epidemiology

I have been reading several articles on nematode life-history for my insects class. [Several articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomopathogenic_nematode) say that Entomopathogenic nematodes(EPNs) are the only nematodes possessing an "optimal balance of biological control attributes". What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is a long-winded way of saying that these are the only nematode genera that are useful for biological control. In particular the article is referring to *Steinernema* and *Heterorhabditis*, both of which genera are used for control of some pest insects.